# What is the etiquette about deleting a competing comment from own post?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

Suppose there is a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question in GIS Meta with two or more answers. One of them is an answer of mine, and another one is a competing answer from a user who has the privilege to delete comments.

So, I post a comment beneath the competing answer expressing why I disagree with it. Something along:

> -1, because [reason to downvote].

The comment is not rude or abusive.

However, the user with the delete comments privilege who is also the author from the commented answer silently deletes my comment*. At that point, it was the sole comment beneath that answer.

<sub>I realize the comment is deleted by chance when revisiting my post, and I know it is the post owner who deletes it because he/she tells me after I ask him/her.</sub>

This is unethical to me, as I believe there is a conflict of interest deleting a contrary opinion from an owned post.

Is such behaviour unethical or I am overreacting? If something, what to do?

Comment: Could your comment have been written without the -1?  Start a discussion without indicating that you had downvoted?  The -1 and reason to me seems quite negative, so I'm suggesting perhaps try with some more constructive criticism?  Please note I haven't seen your comment yet, this is my first thought from reading your question

Comment: Good question. I've experienced this myself, although I didn't even have a competing answer in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting critical comments from one's own posts would be a pretty clear abuse of moderator privileges. If a comment is believed to violate the "Be Nice" policy, it can be left for another moderator to deal with. Simple as that.

Comment: A moderator cannot flag a comment for moderation by another mod.  When a moderator flags a comment it is instantly deleted.  So if the moderator in question had done as you suggest the outcome would have been the same - deleted comment.  See [Allow moderators to flag comments normally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243970/allow-moderators-to-flag-comments-normally)

Comment: Thanks @Midavalo. Updated to reflect that.